# Responsive Picture Gallery

Tags: css, responsive-design

I'm working on a responsive picture gallery and I'm looking to modify some code I found. I've made a jsFiddle to show you what I'm working with.

[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/jFwYU/)

I want to be able to have a couple buttons below each image in the gallery. As you notice, if there is an image underneath an image the image above has its text cut off. I've thought about adding a margin bottom to `.box` as such:

```
.box {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    width: 14.28%;
    padding-bottom: 14.28%;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}
```

[**jsFiddle with margin-bottom**](http://jsfiddle.net/jFwYU/1/)

I'm wondering if there is a better way to approach this. It seems if you re-size the window too small the text overlaps the images.

Comment: What does `responsive` mean in that context?

Comment: Re-size the js fiddle output and you'll see what I mean. The images adjust themselves to screen size.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to make the bottom padding on .box-container 30px:

```
.box_container {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  padding: 10px 10px 30px 10px;
  margin-bottom: -35px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-right: 5px;
}
```

Comment: Yes, that seems to work like my margin-bottom fix. If you try and re-size it smaller you'll see that the text overlaps the image. I know that the screen resolution might not get that small but still, it bothers me a bit haha.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/jFwYU/3/

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background: #EEE;
    font: 10px/13px'Lucida Sans', sans-serif;
}
.box {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    width: 14.28%;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.boxInner img {
    width: 100%;
}

body.no-touch .boxInner:hover .titleBox, body.touch .boxInner.touchFocus .titleBox {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
@media only screen and (max-width : 480px) {
    /* Smartphone view: 1 tile */
    .box {
        width: 100%;
        padding-bottom: 10px;
    }
}
@media only screen and (max-width : 650px) and (min-width : 481px) {
    /* Tablet view: 2 tiles */
    .box {
        width: 50%;
        padding-bottom: 10px;
    }
}
@media only screen and (max-width : 1050px) and (min-width : 651px) {
    /* Small desktop / ipad view: 3 tiles */
    .box {
        width: 33.3%;
        padding-bottom: 10px;
    }
}
@media only screen and (max-width : 1290px) and (min-width : 1051px) {
    /* Medium desktop: 4 tiles */
    .box {
        width: 25%;
        padding-bottom: 10px;
    }
}
@media only screen and (max-width : 1590px) and (min-width : 1291px) {
    /* Large desktop: 5 tiles */
    .box {
        width: 20%;
        padding-bottom: 10px;
    }
}
@media only screen and (max-width : 1920px) and (min-width : 1591px) {
    /* Extra large desktop: 6 tiles */
    .box {
        width: 16.6%;
        padding-bottom: 10px;
    }
}
```

1) Removed position:absolute; for boxInner and box_container

2) Avoid using floats and position:absolute; together

3) Only horizontal dimensions should be defined in percentage, not the vertical ones(padding-bottom:33% is not good)

Comment: Interesting approach but I liked the padding around each image.

Comment: That is easy. Replace padding-bottom:10px; under .box to padding:5px 10px;

Answer (score 0):

It seems that perhaps the simplest solution for this problem would be to modify the css for the box:

```
.box {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    width: 14.28%;
    height: 14.28%;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
}
```

height is a much more semantic way than padding-bottom to get what you are looking for, and to make sure the text displays properly (which probably shouldn't be absolutely positioned, but minor issue), add a margin-bottom.

You could also have the margin-bottom as a percent to have it be a percent of the size of the box, say, 20% or so, but px might be a good idea if you're not worried about teeny tiny boxes being an issue (whole gallery less than 50px)

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

I created something to help a college student get started. I adapted your images to the attached code. There are some features that the student needed that you did not ask for, but you can easily remove them.

I believe it meets the intent of preserving the space between images and allows text for each picture. The text is locked to its picture.

The code is not optimized and can certainly be improved, but it will hopefully put you a little closer to what you wanted,

**Updated: [Example Photo Gallery](https://jsfiddle.net/highdown/wuoxu1e9/4/)**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Photo Viewer</title>
    <style>
        html {
            border: 0 none transparent;
        }

        body {
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
            font-family: arial, tahoma, sans-serif;
            font-weight: 400;
            font-size: 15px;
            background: #FEFADA;
            color: #2C2218;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            border: none;
            text-align: center;
            font-style: normal;
            font-weight: normal;
            font-variant: normal;
            cursor: pointer;
        }

        .picture {
            /*Add venfor specific property*/
            -webkit-column-count: 4;
            /*Set the default to 4 columns*/
            column-count: 4;
            /*Set text line height*/
            line-height: 1.5;
            /*Add venfor specific property*/
            -webkit-column-gap: 15px;
            column-gap: 15px;
            /*Outer margin for picture container*/
            margin: auto 10px;
        }

        /*Switch to three columns at this display width*/
        @media (max-width: 1024px) {
            .picture {
                /*Add venfor specific property*/
                -webkit-column-count: 3;
                column-count: 3;
            }
        }

        /*Switch to two columns at this display width*/
        @media (max-width: 764px) {
            .picture {
                /*Add venfor specific property*/
                -webkit-column-count: 2;
                column-count: 2;
            }
        }

        /*Switch to one columns at this display width*/
        @media (max-width: 480px) {
            .picture {
                /*Add venfor specific property*/
                -webkit-column-count: 1;
                column-count: 1;
            }
        }

        .hide {
            display: none;
        }

        .img, .selected-img {
            width: 100%;
            margin: 8px auto;
            white-space: nowrap;
        }

        .selected-img {
            max-width: 1024px;
        }

        .selected {
            position: fixed;
            margin: 5px auto;
            left: 0;
            right: 0;
            z-index: 10;
            display: block;
        }

        .closeme {
            -webkit-align-content: center;
            left: 0;
            right: 0;
            width: auto;
            margin: auto;
            display: block;
        }

        .disable {
            background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
            width: 100% !important;
            height: 100% !important;
            left: 0;
            right: 0;
            top: 0;
            bottom: 0;
            z-index: 5;
            position: fixed;
        }

        .btn {
            border: 1px;
            border-color: transparent #D1C89D transparent #D1C89D;
            background: #EBE6C1;
            height: 40px;
            margin: auto 0;
            width: 100%;
        }

        .picture-text {
            margin: auto;
            padding: 10px 3px;
            display: table-cell;
            white-space: normal;
        }

        .inline-block {
            display: inline-block;
            white-space: nowrap;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <!-- Hide the selected image window until its needed with the hide class -->
        <div id="selectedWindow" class="hide">
            <button class="closeme btn" onclick="closeWindow()">Click this Button or on the Selected Image to close window.</button>
            <!-- Load the selected image here -->
            <img id="selectedImage" class="selected-img" onclick="closeWindow()" />
        </div>
        <button class="btn" onclick="loadImages()">Load Images</button>
        <div id="imageContainer" class="picture" onclick="loadSelectedPicture(event)"></div>
        <div id="disableMask"></div>
    </div>
    <script type="application/javascript">
        function loadImages() {
            // For DEBUG if you need it: alert("Made it to the function");
            var element = document.getElementById("imageContainer");
            var imageArray = ["http://www.dwuser.com/education/content/creating-responsive-tiled-layout-with-pure-css/images/demo/1.jpg", "http://www.dwuser.com/education/content/creating-responsive-tiled-layout-with-pure-css/images/demo/2.jpg", "http://www.dwuser.com/education/content/creating-responsive-tiled-layout-with-pure-css/images/demo/3.jpg", "http://www.dwuser.com/education/content/creating-responsive-tiled-layout-with-pure-css/images/demo/4.jpg", "http://www.dwuser.com/education/content/creating-responsive-tiled-layout-with-pure-css/images/demo/5.jpg", "http://www.dwuser.com/education/content/creating-responsive-tiled-layout-with-pure-css/images/demo/6.jpg", "http://www.dwuser.com/education/content/creating-responsive-tiled-layout-with-pure-css/images/demo/7.jpg", "http://www.dwuser.com/education/content/creating-responsive-tiled-layout-with-pure-css/images/demo/8.jpg", "http://www.dwuser.com/education/content/creating-responsive-tiled-layout-with-pure-css/images/demo/9.jpg", "http://www.dwuser.com/education/content/creating-responsive-tiled-layout-with-pure-css/images/demo/10.jpg", "http://www.dwuser.com/education/content/creating-responsive-tiled-layout-with-pure-css/images/demo/11.jpg"];
            var picture = "";
            for (var i = 0; i < imageArray.length; i++) {
                // Create an id for each image and add its class.
                picture += "<div><img id=\"i" + i + "\" class=\"img\" src=\"" + imageArray[i] + "\"><div class=\"inline-block\"><div class=\"picture-text\">Here is some text for each image. How long can this text be before we have some issues.</div></div></div>";
                // For DEBUG if you need it: console.log(picture);
            }
            element.innerHTML = picture;
        }

        function loadSelectedPicture(event) {
            var target = event.target || event.srcElement;
            this.stopEventPropagation(event);
            var selectedElement = document.getElementById(target.id);
            var imageElement = document.getElementById("selectedImage");
            if (!selectedElement.src)
                return;
            imageElement.src = selectedElement.src;
            document.getElementById("selectedWindow").className = "selected";
            document.getElementById("disableMask").className = "disable";
        }

        function stopEventPropagation(event) {
            if (!event)
                event = window.event;
            //IE9 & Other Browsers
            if (event.stopPropagation) {
                event.stopPropagation();
            }
            //IE8 and Lower
            else {
                event.cancelBubble = true;
            }
        }

        function closeWindow() {
            document.getElementById("selectedWindow").className = "hide";
            document.getElementById("disableMask").className = "";
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I will try to update this post with a working jsFiddle when I have some free time.