# Photos gallery for full screen website

Tags: javascript, jquery, photo-gallery

I have a website mainly for read comic book online.
So when upload content to web page, most of them are images. My content will be something like this.

```
<p> 
<img src="img1">
<h1>Some text</h1>
<img src="img2">
<img src="img3">
</p>
```

I want when user click img1 it will show full screen. Click next button will show img2 and so on.
is there any photo library for this job.

Comment: Try this library.

http://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightGallery/

Comment: I tried and it work. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Of course.
Very fewer people are familiar with this awesome javascript gallery library. I hope you know basic javascript. 
Read their docs and you will master that just in few minutes. Here is their link below. 
For better understanding try to understand their codes in Codepen.
[Click here to go their official page](http://photoswipe.com)

Answer (score 0):

If you check out this [Stack Overflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18252788/responsive-picture-gallery/47973274#47973274), there are several examples of photo galleries that you can build upon.

You can click **[JSFiddle Photo Gallery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18252788/responsive-picture-gallery/47973274#47973274)** to see the code and run the example.

You can also look at the other examples on the Stack Overflow link. This code is free to use and modify.